# What is the meaning of としてしまう in the following sentence

Tags: expressions, pragmatics

I do not get how としてしまう is used in the following sentence.  If the meaning ofとして = as, for; not even and しまう = to finish doing (something), what do they mean together? (assuming I have split the phrase correctly).

> 男性がイラッ!! としてしまう!? [女性の言いがちワード]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the として meaning as/for, but a simple conjugation of the する verb イラッとする, meaning "to feel annoyed". In addition, the しまう here isn't being used in the sense of "finish doing", but rather the more common sense where it indicates the preceding verb is an unfortunate occurrence.

So 男性がイラッ!!としてしまう!? as a whole means "Guys will feel annoyed?!"

Incidentally, this sentence is loosely linked to the following phrase in the style of a relative clause, so the whole thing could be translated as if it was one sentence:

男性がイラッとしてしまう女性のいいがちワード

This would mean "Words girls tend to say that make guys feel annoyed".

Comment: Is it a common pattern for an onomatopoeia to be followed by とする to form a する verb?

Comment: Yes, I'd call it a pretty standard sort of construction. It's along the same lines as the common use of [onomatopoeia]と on its own as an adverbial form, and [onomatopoeia]とした as an adjectival.